# Why put std::lock before std::lock_guard

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, deadlock

Moving forward with [Concurrency In Action](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/CplusplusConcurrencyInAction_PracticalMultithreading.pdf) I have reached the following example.
Tha author states that if we everytime lock 2 [mutexes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) in the same order, then we are guaranteed to avoid [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).
 Consider this example from the book:

```
class X
{
    private:
    some_big_object some_detail;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    X(some_big_object const& sd):some_detail(sd){}
    friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
    {
       if(&lhs==&rhs){return;}
       std::lock(lhs.m,rhs.m);
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m,std::adopt_lock);
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m,std::adopt_lock);
       swap(lhs.some_detail,rhs.some_detail);
    }
};
```

1. Why do we apply the [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) and then apply 2 [`std::lock_guards`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) with [`std::adopt_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t) instead of just applying 2 `std::lock_guards` one after another??
2. Why cant we just put this 2 [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)es in the [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)??

Comment: (1) Deadlock. (2) Which `scoped_lock` are you talking about? I don't see any `scoped_lock` in the code.

Comment: i mead instead of the three lines with locks, why cant we put 2 mtexes in scopted lock

Comment: @RaymondChen OP is asking why `std::scoped_lock` couldn't have been used instead of `std::lock` and the two `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: Sure, you could do that, if you had a time machine. The book was written in 2012, but `scoped_lock` wasn't introduced until 2017.

Comment: could you please form an answer @FrançoisAndrieux, this is exactly what I was asking. tnx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why do we apply the std::lock and then apply 2 std::lock_guards with std::adopt_lock instead of just applying 2 std::lock_guards one after another??

If you used two [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) without [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) the order of locking for `swap(a, b);` would be the opposite of `swap(b, a);`, where `a` and `b` are `X`s. If one thread tried `swap(a, b);` while another tried `swap(b, a);` they could deadlock. The first thread would own the lock on `a`'s mutex and wait for `b`'s while the second thread would own the lock on `b`'s mutex and wait for `a`'s. Using `std::lock` ensures that the locking order is always consistent.

> Why cant we just put this 2 std::mutexes in the std::scoped_lock??

If you look at the date of publication for the article you linked, c++17 did not exist yet. Since [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) was introduced by c++17, it could not have been used in the article. This kind of locking problem is what `std::scoped_lock` is design to solve and should be used in modern code.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan `std::lock` says : *"Locks the given [`Lockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Lockable) objects `lock1, lock2, ..., lockn` using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock."*. The order the mutex given to `std::lock` are locked is not specified by the standard, but it's guaranteed to be locked in a consistent order for a given set a mutex, regardless of the order they are provided as arguments, such that these kinds of order-based deadlocks won't happen. It's up to the implementaiton how it's done.

Comment: [Here is an in-depth study of how `std::lock` works](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) (or _should_ work).  If your `std::lock` isn't doing this file a bug report.

Comment: I think even if we don't use `std::lock` in the above code, the order of locking for `swap(a, b)` or `swap(b, a)` doesn't matter and there's no deadlock, right? (If the locking order is consistent throughout the entire code). `swap` itself has nothing to do with deadlock, I think.

Comment: @starriet It does matter. If you don't use `std::lock` the first argument is locked first, then the second. So `swap(a, b)` locks in the opposite order of `swap(b, a)` which is when you can get a deadlock.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think I'm missing something. In the OP's code, 1) the mutex `m`s are not swapped. 2) Even if we assume the `m`s are swapped, the changed order of the locks remains consistent(all sequences a->b becomes b->a). How can a->b and b->a coexist? (I wrote a->b to express the sequence of locking a.m then locking b.m)

Comment: @starriet The idea is that there is the implied possibility of two threads trying to swap `a` and `b` at the same time, and we want to make that thread safe. If thread 1 tries to `swap(a, b)` at the same time as thread 2 tries to `swap(b, a)` it will result in a deadlock if the order the mutex are locked isn't the same. In a naive aproach that doesn't use `std::lock` thread 1 could own the lock to `a.m` and block trying to lock `b.m` while thread 2 own the lock to `b.m` and block trying to lock `a.m`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh! The situation you're considering is, somewhere in the code there is `swap(a, b);` (thread 1 tries to execute it), and somewhere else in the code there is `swap(b, a);` (thread 2 tries to execute it), correct? So, if the two _different codes_ `swap(a, b);` and `swap(b, a);` coexist in the project, deadlock can occur unless we use `std::lock`. Now I got you. I was considering the situation where multiple `swap(a, b);` exist but _no_ `swap(b, a);` in the code. In this case, `std::lock` is not necessary I think. Please let me know if I misunderstood. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

`std::lock` is not RAII.   Mutex locks not in RAII is dangerous and scary.  If an exception is thrown you could "leak" a lock.

`std::lock_guard` does not support deadlock safe multiple mutex locking.  But it is RAII, so it makes the rest of the code safer.  If you lock a then b in one spot, and b then a in another, you get code that can deadlock (with one thread holding a and waiting for b, and another thread holding b and waiting for a).

`std::lock` is guaranteed to avoid this through some unspecified manner (which could include a global order on locks).

`std::scoped_lock` is [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).  In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) it is what you should use instead of the sample code you have shown.  It was added because writing that code sucks.  Name mangling and linking issues prevented simply adding variardic support to existing locking primitives like lock guard, which is why it has a different name.

Comment: Question) Why doesn't `std::lock_guard` support deadlock safe multiple mutex locking? Is it related to the fact that it supports RAII? I think if the order of the locking is preserved(e.g. lock a then b), we can avoid deadlock, can't we?

Comment: @starriet there is no good reason.  Well, ABI compatibility.  Use `scoped_lock` in more modern versions of C++.  Lock guard lacks a multiple mutex overload.  In theory you can carefully use it and avoid deadlocks, but instead use unengaged locks and std lock.  Mutex based multithreading is insanely error prone: if you do it manually you'll make mistakes *and* make maintenance errors and you *will* have deadlocks.

Comment: So, "in theory" I don't need `std::lock(lhs.m,rhs.m)` in the above code in the question, but I do need it because not using std::lock is error-prone and I'll make mistakes, right? Thank you. I didn't understand why just using the consistent order of two `std::lock_guard`s (lock_a first, and then lock_b) throughout the code is not enough. It _is_ enough only in theory :)

Comment: @starriet Maintaining a global order is one thing for two locks.  But with more than 2 avoiding a deadlock can require backoff.  Use std lock and so long as nobody holds locks when locking there are no deadlocks, guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

1. The reason is that `std::lock` locks the mutexes in some unspecified order, yet the order is the same in all threads, thus protecting us from deadlocks. So, it may be `lock(lhs.m)` and then `lock(rhs.m)`, or the other way round. This means we don't know which of `std::lock_guard`s to create first: for `lhs.m` or for `rhs.m`.
2. It seems that the book was written with C++11 as the basis standard. `std::scoped_lock` comes only in C++17.