# Doesn't multiple std::lock_guard guarantee the order of locks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In the cppreference.com `std::lock` [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock), there is a code like this:

```
    // use std::lock to acquire two locks without worrying about 
    // other calls to assign_lunch_partner deadlocking us
    {
        std::lock(e1.m, e2.m);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::adopt_lock);
```

1. I thought the consistent ordering (lock `lk1` first, and then lock `lk2`) across the different threads is enough to avoid deadlock, but why do we need `std::lock(e1.m, e2.m)`?
   <sub>(I also read other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50046067/10027592) but still not sure why just locking with multiple `std::lock_guard`s are not enough even though they're locking in the same order.)</sub>
2. Is this related to the fact that `std::lock_guard` supports RAII style?

**Edit: (question resolved)**

1. We ***don't*** need the `std::lock(e1.m, e2.m)` if all occurrences of the declaration of `lk1` and `lk2` in the whole code have the same (consistent) order. I.e., `e1.m` is locked first and then `e2.m` is locked in all places in the code.
2. Thus, `std::lock(e1.m, e2.m)` is just some kind of insurance for safety, just in case `lk2` is declared first and then `lk1` is declared(`e2.m` gets locked first and then `e1.m` gets locked) ***somewhere else*** in the code. (But, in practice, this "insurance" is important because we make mistakes.)

Thanks to all who commented, and please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Having two `lock_guard`s doesn't prevent you from locking these objects in opposite order somewhere else in your code. Having a single `lock_guard` handles this case.

Comment: With a single `lock_guard` object, the `lock_guard` constructor gets to choose the order in which it calls `lock()` on the arguments you passed to it (and therefore it can choose consistently, perhaps by sorting them by memory location?).  With multiple `lock_guards`, you choose the order in which the mutexes are locked, based on the order you declare the `lock_guard` objects.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner As you said _"you choose the order ... based on the order you declare the `lock_guard` objects."_, the order is `lk1` first and then `lk2`, and this order applies to all threads, right?(unless I declare with reversed order in another part of my code) Then why there can be a deadlock, and why do we need `std::lock` to prevent deadlock?

Comment: What do you think ensures that all other threads will lock `lk1` and `lk2` (or, more accurately, `e1.m` and `e2.m`) in that order?

Comment: @Peter I thought declaring `lk1` and then `lk2` has the same effect as `e1.m.lock()` and then `e2.m.lock()`. Well, `A; B;` doesn't execute `B;` first and then `A;`, does it?  What am I missing here?

Comment: It does.   But what ensures other threads lock `e1.m` and `e2.m` in that order?

Comment: @Peter Hmm.. I just simply thought all other threads see the same code..(the only difference is the accessibility by owning the mutex) Could you please tell me on what occasion `e2.m` gets locked first and then `e1.m` is locked? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You (or someone) could write a different function that declares the two lock_guards in a different order, and then you’d have a potential deadlock.  Otoh if all functions use only a single lock-guard, that can’t happen.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Then, if I (or someone) don't write any codes that declare the two `lock_guard`s in a reversed order, there is no deadlock?

Comment: Correct; deadlocks can only occur if different threads lock multiple locks in different orders.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you. Then the role of `std::lock(e1.m, e2.m)` in the above example is to prevent the deadlock from possibly differently ordered declarations of `lock_guard`s in other parts of the code, right? (No need of `std::lock(e1.m, e2.m)` if all `lock_guard`s are declared in consistent order). Thanks again for your confirmation!